# Text near the img

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a responsive food site, and i wanna place a text near a img and doing it a multyple time. I try whit somethings like this

```
<div class="content">

        <div class="recepie">

      
            <div class="img-recepie">
        
                <img src="../Images/Slide01.jpg" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat labore, sint cupiditate distinctio tempora reiciendis.</p>
                               </div>

        </div>


        <div class="recepie">

      
            <div class="img-recepie2">
        
                <img src="../Images/Slide02.jpg" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat labore, sint cupiditate distinctio tempora reiciendis.</p>
                             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Flex-box is a good solution for these cases.

Add following `css`:

```css
.recepie {
  display: flex;
}
```